# Why do we need async when Future implicit declare await

Tags: dart

Is there some syntax sugar, I can not see - why do we need to define `async` in the following:

```
Future myFuture() => Future<String>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => "await the future!");

void main() async {
    await myFuture().then((str) => print('We have to $str'));
}
```

When we can do the following without the `async` keyword:

```
void main() {
  Future<String>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => "implicit await the future!").then((str) => print('We have to $str'));
}
```

One could think that `await` is implicit when using `Future` but note, it works without defining main as `async`

Comment: `async` prepares the method for `await`.  Note that, in your example, an `async` method does not return `Future<String>`; it returns the awaited value of the Future, which is of type `String`.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await), which describes this process in detail.

Comment: You don't *need* `await`.  `async`/`await` is syntactic sugar for using the `Future` API (registering a `Future.then` callback and potentially other completion callbacks).  The point of [syntactical sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) is to make code easier to read and write.  Code that uses `await` usually is *much* easier to understand and is much less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* to use `async` or `await` in this case.

The reason is that no-one ever waits for the return value of `main`, so it doesn't matter whether `main` is `async` and returns a future. Not unless you use `await`.

And the way you use `await` here also makes no real difference.
That `await` just makes the `main` function wait for another future before it completes the future returned by `main`. Again, and nobody ever looks at the value returned by `main`, so it doesn't matter when that future completes, or even if it is a future at all.

So, you can remove `async` and `await`, and all it changes is what `main` returns, and when the future it returns completes, something nobody actually cares about.